# how to query a list of values names in a column of PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL, and am having trouble with a relatively simple query, but for some odd reason I cannot get it to work.

I am trying to pull a dataset based on values within that dataset meeting certain criteria. In python, it's relatively simple, but I cannot import the dataset of 20 million rows, and only need about 20 thousand.

Logically, I'd think you can pass a list of values to SQL to filter based on columns, but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is below:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE column_1 = ['value_in_column_1', 'another_value_in_column_1', 'third_value_in_column_1']
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 250;
```

However, that returns syntax error messages.

My though process was that since I can query by saying `WHERE column_1 = value_in_column_1`, I should be able to add additional values to it, but it seems it's not the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use column_1  IN ('value_in_column_1', 'another_value_in_column_1')
IN is for list

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to use *in* with a specific list of values, such as

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE column_1 in('value_in_column_1', 'another_value_in_column_1',...)
```